# How to allow usage of FilePicker in WindowsStore App?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

Using c#, Windows Store App, VS 2013

Try to open File Picker, using next simple code:

```
    private async void OkBtnClick(IUICommand command)
    {
        if (this.EnsureUnsnapped())
        {
            FileOpenPicker fop = new FileOpenPicker();
            fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
            fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
            fop.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
            fop.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

            fop.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
            StorageFile requestedFile = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();

            if (requestedFile != null)
            {
             //TODO:
            }
        }
    }

    internal bool EnsureUnsnapped()
    {
        // FilePicker APIs will not work if the application is in a snapped state.
        // If an app wants to show a FilePicker while snapped, it must attempt to unsnap first
        bool unsnapped = ((ApplicationView.Value != ApplicationViewState.Snapped) 
            || ApplicationView.TryUnsnap());
        if (!unsnapped)
        {
            Extensions.NotifyUser("Cannot unsnap app...", statusNotificationBlock);
        }

        return unsnapped;
    }
```

Also add capability in appmanifest file for Pictures Library:

[image]

But during running got exception : `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` on line `StorageFile requestedFile = await fop.PickSingleFileAsync();`.

Question: Why I got this exception if all required access provided, Also i try to launch VS2013 with Administrator rights - result - same.

---

For creating this code use [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771180.aspx)

Comment: The C# sample given works for me in VS2013 : 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba

Comment: thanks, need to check